# Need help on adding winning count

Tags: javascript, counter

I'd like to add a winning count on top of this existing function but I don't know how. I have very very little knowledge about coding and nobody near me knows either. I hope I can get some help from here. thanks!

Edit: I tried adding the whole code but it won't let me save the edits. However, I put the whole code here:https://codeshare.io/8p63Wj for everyone's reference.

```html
function addPhoto(data, mode) {
    // DATA
    let userName = data.uniqueId;
    let userAvatar = data.profilePictureUrl;
    let word = ['Nice going','That’s better than ever','That’s first class work','I’m impressed','Nothing can stop you now','Well done','Good job','You did it','That’s the way','You rock','I knew you could do it','Keep up the good work','That’s clever','Way to go','Outstanding','Tremendous','Fantastic','You are amazing','No one can beat you','You are the chosen one'];
    let words = word[Math.floor(Math.random()*word.length)];

    // Add
    if (mode == "winner")
        {
        addContent(
            `<div style="text-align:center;font-size: 1.25rem;">
                <div style='padding-bottom:.25rem;color:#1881FF;'> `+words+`</div>
                <div style='padding-bottom:.5rem;font-weight: bold;color:#20B601;'>`+userName+` ❗</div>
                <div>
                    <img src="`+userAvatar+`" style="width:135px;height:135px;border-radius: 15px;"/>
                </div>
            </div>`
        );
    } else {
        addContent(
            `<div style="text-align:center;font-size: 1.25rem;">
                <div style='padding-bottom:.25rem;'>Thanks</div>
                <div style='padding-bottom:.5rem;font-weight: bold;color:#EA0C0C;'>`+userName+`</div>
                <div>
                    <img src="`+userAvatar+`" style="width:135px;height:135px;border-radius: 15px;"/>
                </div>
            </div>`
        );
    }

    // Sound
    playSound(3);
}
```

Comment: If you are going to copy code, make sure you copy it completely. The code you posted is missing a lot of code and of course doesn't work (I assume the complete code does work). It's impossible to add a count to a function that we have no idea how it actually works.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I tried putting the whole code but it won't let me save the edits because my post is mostly just code. However, I put the whole code somewhere else for anyone's reference. It's here: https://codeshare.io/8p63Wj
Please have a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use variables that are "rememberd" outside of the scope of the function. That way the page will still remember the value after the function is done. But you do increase those variables inside the function, every time they win for example.

```html
let plays = 0;
let wins = 0;
let losses = 0;

function addPhoto(data, mode) {
    // DATA
    let userName = data.uniqueId;
    let userAvatar = data.profilePictureUrl;
    let word = ['Nice going','That’s better than ever','That’s first class work','I’m impressed','Nothing can stop you now','Well done','Good job','You did it','That’s the way','You rock','I knew you could do it','Keep up the good work','That’s clever','Way to go','Outstanding','Tremendous','Fantastic','You are amazing','No one can beat you','You are the chosen one'];
    let words = word[Math.floor(Math.random()*word.length)];

    // Add
    plays++;
    if (mode == "winner")
    {
        wins++;
        addContent('<p>Plays: '+plays+' Wins: '+wins+' Losses: '+losses+'</p>');
    } else {
        losses++;
        addContent('<p>Plays: '+plays+' Wins: '+wins+' Losses: '+losses+'</p>');
    }

    // Sound
    playSound(3);
}
```